# Numpy Advanced Indexing and basic indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, view, copy

I am trying to understand a specific part of [this article](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

> The definition of advanced indexing means that `x[(1,2,3),]` is fundamentally different than `x[(1,2,3)]`. The latter is equivalent to `x[1,2,3]` which will trigger basic selection while the former will trigger advanced indexing. Be sure to understand why this occurs.

I have experimented with the following code.

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> a = np.arange(50).reshape(5,10)    
>>> b = a[(2,2)]    
>>> bb = a[(2,2),]    
>>> a[2,2] = 50 # a[2,2] was 22 in the first place 
>>> b
22  # this outcome confuses me!
```

I think `b = a[(2,2)]` would get a view so when I change `a[2,2]` this would do so.

`bb = a[(2,2),]` would receive the copy so nothing would happen even if I do something on a.

But as I change `a[2,2]` from 22 to 50

What I expect `b = a[(2,2)]` would change to 50 a and `bb = a[(2,2),]` is going to remain the same.

What's wrong with all of this? Am I misunderstanding or missing something important?

If it is, Please correct me and thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Basic selection" (i.e. indexing as opposed to slicing) doesn't create a view, it creates a copy.  In order to be a view, you need to pass a one-element slice (slicing, unlike indexing, is always a view).

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.arange(50).reshape(5,10)    
b = a[2:3,2:3].squeeze()    
a[2,2] = 50 
b

array(50)
```

You can also get the same thing with `b = a[2, 2, None].squeeze()`, which triggers "fancy" indexing," which is a sort of a hybrid between selection and slicing and reurns a view.  Using "advanced" indexing (as you did, or like `b = a[[2],[2]]`) is a variant of indexing, and returns a copy.

And yes, keeping those various types of indexing straight isn't easy for beginners.  And creating a view of one element is still kind of hacky.  A 0-dim array like `array(50)` can be used in most cases like a normal `int`.

To make it even more confusing, `a[2,2]` *is* interpreted as a view when on the left side of an equals sign, but not on the right.  It has to do with `=` being interpreted as `.__setitem__()`.

Comment: I think i understand most part of your answer but could you maybe explain b = a[2, 2, None].squeeze() ,what does None at the end of index stand for? I saw this just the other day but still can't figure out what this is!Thanks!

Comment: I use the similar operation like b=a[2,2,...] and it seems that return the view! Do these two operations(: and ...) actually trigger the basic indexing?

Comment: Yeah, `a[2,2,...]` triggers fancy indexing as `...` essentially means "include all the other dimensions", which counts as a slice even if there are no other dimensions.  Since you're then mixing slicing and indexing, it's considered "fancy" and it returns a view.  Probably the best solution as it doesn't need `squeeze()`

Comment: `:` will only trigger fancy indexing if there is actually a dimension there.  If you do `a[2,2,:]` you'll get an `IndexError` becasue there is no third dimension in `a`

Comment: `None` adds another dimension (it's the same as `np.newaxis` but shorter to write) which is considered a slice. You then get rid of that dimension with `squeeze()`

Comment: I really appreciate,just last check if I type something like this a[[1,2,3],:,[4,2,3]],I think this would  trigger fancy indexing,right?

Comment: It should, yes.